# Java Ascii to String Decryption

Tags: java

[Original Question](http://venus.cs.qc.cuny.edu/~knemoto/pdf/assignment1.pdf) (Problem 3)

I'm completing a problem for class that requires converting a string message from ascii with a key to a decoded String message. I've tried both accessing the string from message.charAt(i) and by converting it to a char array but both times I get this weird out put on the console.

[image: screenshot of console]

This is the method I have running

```
public static char[] decrypt(String message) {
    char[] decoded = new char[message.length()];
    char[] newmessage = message.toCharArray();
    int ascii;
    for(int key=0; key<=100; key++) {
        for(int i=0; i<message.length(); i++) {
            ascii = ( (int)newmessage[i] + 127) - 32;
            if(ascii > 126)
                decoded[i] = (char)((int)newmessage[i] - key);
            else
                decoded[i] = (char)((((int)newmessage[i] - key) +127) -32);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(decoded);
    return decoded;
}
```

This is where I called it in main

```
    System.out.println("Problem 3");
    String message =  ":mmZ\\dxZmx]Zpgy";
    System.out.println("Message Received: ");
    System.out.println(message);
    decrypt(message);
```

I can't seem to figure out where I went wrong with it. The expected output is for each key to be printed with the corresponded decoded message. The 88th key will show the message is "Attack at Dawn!".

Comment: Why you are looping through 100 times? What is your actual and expected output.

Comment: part of the question was that the key for the code was between 1 and 100 and we had to show the gibberish produced by every other key. I will post a link to the original question.

Comment: The message is actually in unicode as Java use it by default

Comment: is this in regards to the title? or is this something that has to be addressed in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey first you need to now wich **Key decode** the message  of `:mmZ\\dxZmx]Zpgy` So for go for the easy part try to decode first the `Hey` message with your algorithm that you made, and you forgot the most escenssial part:

```
if(originalChar + key > 126) then
     EncryptedChar = 32 + ((originalChar + key) - 127)
else
     EncryptedChar = (originalChar + key)
```

So you in your if statement you are missing the minus key

```
 if(ascii - key > 126)
```

Always go and re read your question.

```
    for(int key=0; key<=100; key++) {
        for(int i=0; i<message.length(); i++) {
            ascii = ( (int)newmessage[i] + 127) - 32;
            if(ascii - key > 126)
                decoded[i] = (char)((int)newmessage[i] - key);
            else
                decoded[i] = (char)((((int)newmessage[i] - key) +127) -32);
        }
        System.out.println("Decoded with i=" +key +":"+new String(decoded)); // For check what is the correct message. 
    }
```

**Spoiler**
The MEssage is:
Attacck at dawn!

Answer (score 2):

If all you need is decode from ASCII to Java String, then one of correct ways of doing it is

```
char [] output = StandardCharsets.US_ASCII.decode(ByteBuffer.wrap(input)).array();
```

Based on your performance requirements, you may want to preallocate buffers, and may be the decoder (in the above example Charset::decode will create one on the fly).